# xsltproc + xslt + xsd + xml

Tags: linux, c, xml, xslt, xsd

Вопрос в следующем, как правильно выполнить `xsltproc` с учетом что хочется:

сгенерировать из XSD файла с помощью XSLT файла то что там запланировано.
про версию `xsltproc` там нечто мутное:

```
# xsltproc -V
Using libxml 20706, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20706, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
libxslt 10128 was compiled against libxml 20706
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20706
```

на выходе имеем одну и туже ошибку вне зависимости от комбинаций ключей:

```
compilation error: file index.xsd line 2 element schema
xsltParseStylesheetProcess : document is not a stylesheet
```

как с этим бороться? и умеет ли оно так на самом деле? (судя по документации, должно уметь). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Так хотя бы покажите, как вызываете xsltproc. Судя по ошибке, ему передаётся не тот файл.

Comment: Если не сложно, приведите пример как правильно, с учётом что есть 2 файла, xslt и xsd. Все комбинации запуска согласно хелпу xsltproc к успеху не привели, не вижу смысла приводить все комбинации которые были опробованы.

Comment: `xsltproc xslt xsd` - первым параметром идёт stylesheet, потом один или несколько входных xml. Если ошибка остаётся, значит показывайте свой xslt, хотя бы первые три строки.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось без опциональных ключей однако :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, оформите пожалуйста в виде ответа, я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html), первым параметром (если не использовать опции) идёт stylesheet, потом один или несколько входных xml:

```
xsltproc xslt xsd
```